# UC4 Job Execution with Webservice

Tags: web-services, api, job-scheduling, uc4, automic

We need to execute a UC4 job on demand whenever it is needed, not on scheduler basis. Are there any APIs / webservices to start a job execution, to stop job execution and to ask for status of the job, provided by UC4 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve that.

1. One is to use the Java API, build a Java application, that will call your Job (https://docs.automic.com/documentation/webhelp/english/AWA/12.0/AE/12.0/API/index.html)
2. Another way is to use the internal webservice, which you need to install first, where you can also execute an object - among other things (https://docs.automic.com/documentation/webhelp/english/AWA/12.0/DOCU/12.0/AWA%20Guides/help.htm#AE_AWA_Source/Integration/ucacrt.htm%3FTocPath%3DIntegration%2520Guide%7CInternal%2520Webservices%7C_____3)
3. You could also build some job execution build on other events (file event, etc.) or on a shared resource (trigger entry in a static VARA object) - but those are not very clean and maintainable ways of doing such a thing.

I personally would use the webservice, if not available the Java API. You can find the API in the uc4.jar file that should come along with the installation package (lib folder) or as separate downloadable artifact on the automic download center.